# Let G = $U(14) \times Q$ and $N = \langle(9,j)\rangle$. Find $G/N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Let G = $U(14) \times Q$ where $U(14)$ is the multiplication modulo $14$ group and $Q$ is the quaternion group. Let $N = \langle(9,j)\rangle$. Find $G/N$.

I calculated that $\langle(9,j)\rangle$ is  $\{(9,j),(11,-1),(1,1)\}$ but don't know how to proceed. Will $G/N$ be the group consisting of all $16$ cosets, considering $U(14) \times Q$ is of order $48$ and $N$ is of order $3$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use Mathjax for math formulas.

Comment: My apologies, I am unfamiliar with Mathjax, but I will try my best!

Comment: It’s what the site uses; you’ve been around for 8 months... [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Are you sure you've got all the elements of $N$?

Comment: I believe so, 9*9=81 mod 14 = 11, j*j = -1, 11*9 = 99 mod 14 = 1, and -1*-1 = 1, bringing us back to the identity element of 1,1.

Comment: You write $11*9$, but then $-1*-1$ which should be $-1*j$ right?